How to remove the built-in web browser in an APK file?
do you know how to remove the built-in web browser in an APK file? This APK is not a standalone web browser app, but a social media app. I am looking at the detail elements inside the APK file but don't know how to find and remove the built-in web browser inside this APK file.
detailed APK Package image
I try to find WebView and built-in web browser inside the APK package but I can't find anything related to them. I want to find them and remove them safely, and then repack APK file, so I can install this APK without the built-in web browser

To find references to WebView you have to decompile the app using apktool it also allows to modify the code. For searching without modifying you can use Jadx-Gui.

What suggests that there is a "built-in web browser" in the APK file?
